# How to remove pop-up banner while making a rolling GIF using glenn/gif-scroll-animation on Apify

Tags: scroll, animated-gif, webpage-screenshot, apify

I wanted to take a GIF rolling screenshot of an entire webpage and found this tool on Apify: glenn/gif-scroll-animation

Unfortunatey, there's a pop-up banner which blocks the view that I need to get rid of. If anyone has experience with such a problem or can help me out here I would appreciate it.

Here's the GIF: https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/prJkEduX5c2WPpyF5/records/ymijeans.com-scroll_original

I haven't tried anything yet and am still exploring.